# Specified cast is not valid using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have many check box lists for searching, but when select multiple checks for search then getting an error, below is my full code:

```
private DataTable list(String dbObject, String filterName, String filterValue,string PositonId,string Status)
{
    NameValuePairList objNameValuePairList = new NameValuePairList();
    objNameValuePairList.Add(new NameValuePair("@FilterValue", filterValue, PositonId, Status));
    objNameValuePairList.Add(new NameValuePair("@Action", "FilterBy" + filterName, PositonId, Status));
    DataTable dt = dl.Search_RegisterationInfo(dbObject, objNameValuePairList, PositonId, Status);
    return dt;
}

public DataTable list(String dbOject, FilterList myFilterList,string PositonId,string Status)
{
    // gets a collection(dataset) of all unique filters(datatables) and also group all subfilters(rows) under each filter
    DataTable dt;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // a filter may be a Nationality or a Qualification 
    foreach (Filter item in myFilterList)
    // a subfilter may be Indian or Expatriate under the filter Nationality 
    {
        // another subfilter may be Bachelor degree or Master Degree under the filter Qualification
        dt = list(dbOject, item.getFilterName, item.getFilterValue, PositonId,Status);
        dt.TableName = item.getFilterName;
        // datatables are named based on the filters
        if (ds.Tables.Count == 0)
            // so we get a collection of unique filters (datatables) in the dataset
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        // add new filter without checking, since for the first time, no conflicts are possible
        else
        {
            bool tableMatchFound = false;
            foreach (DataTable newdt in ds.Tables)
                if (newdt.TableName == dt.TableName)
                {
                    // see if filter is already present in the dataset
                    tableMatchFound = true;
                    // when the current filter is already present in the dataset
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        ds.Tables[newdt.TableName].ImportRow(dr);

                }
            // importrow() adds distinct new subfilters to the existing filter, duplicate items are not added
            if (!tableMatchFound)
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
        // if the filter does not exist, add the new filter to the collection
    }
    // the entire collection of filters will contain duplicate items
    // distinct items from the entire collection is filtered out in the next section
    dt = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
    // get the structure of the first filter as they all apply to the same table object  
    if (ds.Tables.Count == 1)
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
    // if there is only one filter, no filtering is required
    else
        // if there are more than one, compare each subfilter of every other filter with the subfilters of the first filter
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            // each subfilter from the first filter is used as a pivot
            int rowMatchFound = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                // search all filters except the first one
                foreach (DataRow newdr in ds.Tables[i].Rows)
                    // select each subfilter from all the filter
                    if ((int)dr["id"] == (int)newdr["id"])
                        rowMatchFound++;
            if (rowMatchFound == ds.Tables.Count)
                // a match is found exactly once in all the filters
                dt.ImportRow(dr);
            // the final item is selected so that is is present in all the filters   
        }
    return dt;
}
```

Exception is:

```
Specified cast is not valid
```

I am getting exception in below line:

```
if ((int)dr["id"] == (int)newdr["id"])
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess in case of multiple checks, you got a comma separated value into `newdr["id"]`? Anyway do you see any stack trace in the exception?

Comment: I m not getting any values and getting directly error. @RahulNikate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `dr["id"]` or the value of `newdr["id"]` is empty or not an `integer`.
So make sure you have valid value in both `dr["id"]` and `newdr["id"]` before casting to `integer`.

Comment: SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.RegistrationId) as id, t1.RegistrationId, t1.GivenName, t1.Email, t1.Nationality, t1.CellPhone, t1.ExperienceYear, t1.Title
FROM         Table_RegistrationInfo AS t1 INNER JOIN
                      Table_ApplicationsInfo AS t2 ON t1.Email = t2.AppliedCandidateId
WHERE     (t1.Nationality = @FilterValue) AND (t2.AppliedPositionId = @PositionId) and (t2.Status=@Status ).

Comment: The above is my select query.

Comment: You need to keep breakpoint at `if ((int)dr["id"] == (int)newdr["id"])` and check the value in visual studio QuickWatch

Comment: If you dont mind, can i send you, the project zip file on this email id: rahulnikate@gmail.com.

Comment: No It's not the right way. I told you in my above comment that you need to keep break point at error statement and check the values of `dr["id"]` and `newdr["id"]`. That will resolve your issue.

Comment: Ok bro thanks and i will check and update your answer soon.